# How to fix buggy webkit-text-size-adjust on iOS5 and iOS6?

Tags: ios, css, webview

I am getting incorrect line height rendered when using `-webkit-text-size-adjust` CSS property in UIWebView under iOS 5 and iOS 6. There seems to be a bug in iOS 5 and also in iOS 6, but the behavior is different, and I am trying to fix the presentation so that it works on all IOS versions.

What I am trying to achieve: I am loading the following HTML code into a UIWebView. The code merely sets the font size, the line height, and the text size adjustment on all text.

```
 <html><head>
 <style language="text/css">
 body {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust : 50%;
 }
 p {
   font-size: 2em;
   line-height: 3em;
  /* line-height: 150%; */  
 }
 </style>
 </head><body>
 <p>Text text text... </p>
 </body>
```

The value 50% of the attribute `-webkit-text-size-adjust` should reduce (by 50%) the size of the entire text. It makes sense to reduce *both* the font size and the line height at the same time, or else the text will look quite ugly. Now, it seems that neither iOS 5.1 nor iOS 6 do this consistently. (In my application, I have to use the attribute `-webkit-text-size-adjust` because the user should be able to change the text size.)

The behavior of iOS 5.1 is to reduce the font size; the line height remains at the same value. So iOS 5.1 will interpret the above HTML as if I had written `font-size: 1em; line-height: 3em;`. A UIWebView on iOS 5.1 will show small text with huge gaps between the lines.

The solution for iOS 5.1 was to write `line-height: 150%;` rather than `line-height: 3em`. Then iOS 5.1 kept the `line-height` value unchanged at 150%, while the font size was reduced. The text display was therefore correct.

The behavior of iOS 6.0, as follows from my tests, is to reduce *both* the font-size and the line-height values, -- even if the line height value is given in *percent*. (This seems to be a bug.) Therefore, iOS 6.0 will display this text as if I had written `font-size: 1em; line-height: 75%;`. The result is that the line height is computed to be 75% of the font size, i.e. the lines of text are so close together they almost overlap.

The solution on iOS 6.0 is to write `line-height: 3em;`. But this will not work on iOS 5.1.

I don't think there is a CSS attribute that is sensitive to the iOS version... How can I make my application work on both iOS versions?

Comment: No solution found so far; bug report submitted to Apple.

Comment: This is an annoying one.

Comment: All I figured so far is that I can set the line-height attribute dynamically in the HTML document (using `[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]`). So I have written quite ugly code that first, reads the initial value of line-height, then stores it in the HTML document as another attribute, then every time dynamically recomputes the new line-height attribute. Lots of javascript code, brittle, only to support iOS 5.x and iOS 6.x together.

Comment: Another approach to a solution: Obtain the WebView's user agent in Javascript, parse the result. The User agent should contain some indication on whether we are running under iOS 5 or iOS 6. Javascript code can then set CSS attributes accordingly. I did not yet test this solution, for lack of time. It will still be brittle JS code, but at least no native code is required to distinguish between iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Comment: Have you tried writing in css "line-height" twice? first with 3em, and in the next line 150% (or in the opposite order) and see what happens across 5.1 and 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it like this `{ line-height:1.5 }`. It's equates to 3 with a 2em font, but tells the device to render the line-height at 1.5x greater than the font, rather than a hardcoded `em` value.

**EDIT:** still don't think it's a bug. I don't think you're telling the CSS enough before firing the size-adjust.

The following code looks identical between both iOS 5.1 and 6.0:

```
html { font-size:40px }
body {
font-size:0.5em; /* without this.. */
-webkit-text-size-adjust : auto; /* 50% is arbitrary */
}
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom:3em;
}


<p>Text text text...</p>
<p>Text text text...</p>
<p>Text text text...</p>
<p>Text text text...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem I have solved in a very-very ugly way the problem:

At launching I am getting the iOS version and  I am storing in my app part.
Than when I need to work differently than I am doing and

```
if(osVersion < 5){
// iOS 4.3 properly working code here
}
else if (osVersion < 6){
// iOS 5.0 and 5.1 properly working code here
}
else{
// iOS 6 properly working code here.
}
```